# How to Get Ubuntu and Windows to Accept Static Address Provided by ISP

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, vmware

[intercaces file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aynn7.jpg)

I am Paying for a block of 5 static WAN IP addresses form my ISP.  I have a modem provided by them that is set in bridged mode (ARRIS TG1682).  Because of the bridged mode, One of the 4 Ethernet ports on the modem is usable for the internet.  This port Is connected to a Nighthawk X6 Router via CAT 6 cable into the router.  Coming Out of the Router is another cat 6 cable connecting to a Windows 7 professional 64-bit host running Virtualbox(5.1.30) and VMware workstation (12.5.0).  Both of these have Linux Virtual Machines, running different distributions of UBUNTU.  one is 16.04 the other is 17.04.  Both of these are non-headless.

Issue: VMware Virtual machines  (regardless of OS cannot connect to the internet, Regardless of the VMnet I am using).  In VirtualBox, I can connect to the internet using DHCP. not static.    Both Linux Distributions are running the exact same copy of the /etc/network/interfaces file. (see screenshot).  How do I get these distributions of Linux to use one of the other 4 static address provided by my ISP?  I have also tried the same interfaces file on a pc that has Ubuntu installed and not running through virtualization software.  Please Advise.

Comment: I set at static address on the router provided by the ISP rather than try to set it within the OS.

Comment: If your router is running NAT, which it will do by default, only the router will have a public IP address.